# How to terminate the session time of Gmail when OneLogin session times out?

Tags: google-chrome, onelogin

I am using OneLogin to sign in to Gmail. When my OneLogin session times out, I would like to be automatically logged out of Gmail as well. Is there a way to do this?

We implemented Onelogin and sync it with Google G-suite in order to have access to G-mail via our Onelogin platform, the problem is that Onelogin Session is closed or the session timeout logs out the Onelogin account the Google Session keeps open and I would like it to end it as soon as Onelogin session ends, meaning that the users will only get access to their email as soon they are logged in Onelogin.

[Basically this will be the final look for the user, and they will be able to use google as usual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fzGh.png)

I tried:

1. Modify Session time and timeout in Onelogin but it did not helped.
2. Tried to modify session time in G-suite (I have admin permissions) but it did not worked since the session kept going no matter what.
3. I have tried to find a setting in Gmail to automatically log me out when my OneLogin session times out. I have not been able to find such a setting.

If you completely log out of Google and try to log in you are redirected to the onelogin portal so that is working as intended but the session will never die after that only the user explicitly closes the session manually every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.